# C# EF Core 6 How do I pass connection string into Context constructor as a string and not as an option

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I have a strange requirement here.  We have a ton of databases that are basically idential but with different clients.  So each db has the same table structures.  With that being said, I can't use the standard way of setting up the connectionstring in the startup.  I would like to see if there is a way I can pass the connectionstring in the contructor without it being the DbContextOptions<> object.   We use to be able to do that in earlier versions of EF but now it's expecting that option in the base().

The other option is just doing raw ADO with a command object, which I REALLY don't want to do, I would prefer if I could use EF.

So this is what it looks like, but would prefer to have a second constructor that allows the connectionString to be passed in.  NO Start Up or NO appsettings.json, just want to pass in a string with the connectionString.

`

> ```
> public  class Context : DbContext
> {
>     public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options) // <== base expects only options
>     {
>         Database.SetCommandTimeout(9000);
>     }
>
>     public Context(string connectionString) : base()
>     {
>         this.Database.Connection ????? What to do here
>     }
>     
>
>     public DbSet<Transcription> Transcriptions { get; set; }
>
>
>     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
>     {
>         base.OnModelCreating(builder);
>         builder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
>
>         builder.Entity<Transcription>().ToTable("Transcriptions", "dbo");
>     }
>
> }`
> ```

Any idea why this keeps throwing errors or why it won't allow me to set the connectionString instead of using options?

I have looked an keep getting old solutions from 12+ years ago, nothing for EF 6

Comment: EF6 tag is for old .NET Framework iteration of EF are you sure you are using it with .NET 6?

Comment: sorry, it's EF Core 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly more convenient would be to use [multitenancy approaches described in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy) but if you still want to use just the ctor you can override the `OnConfiguring` method and use connection string from the ctor there:

```cs
public class Context : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public Context(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            // setup options - provider, connection string, etc.
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

Or manually building options from the connection string:

```cs
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(string connectionString):base(BuildOpts(connectionString))
    {

    }

    private static DbContextOptions<Context> BuildOpts(string connectionString) =>
        new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>()
            .UseNpgsql(connectionString) // setup options - provider, connection string, etc.
            .Options;
}
```

Comment: On your second example, the BuildOpts, that doesn't work since I'm using SQL Server, I replaced the UseNpgsql with UseSqlServer and it throws an error with the connectionString part.

Comment: @AndrewHarbert obviously you need to replace the `UseNpgsql` with provider for db you are using. What error are you getting exactly? Are you sure you are passing correct connection string?